# how to get request-response logs on weblogic server

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, portlet

I am running a portlet application on springs on weblogic server. If i want to see the request -responses logs in my application, what are the configuration settings that i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you need HTTP request log, follow documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/logging/EnableAndConfigureHTTPLogs.html

If you want more data or response, you need to write (or find) servlet filter that will dump requested data to file